# QSound error - reference?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to play a sound from a QSound object. I can't see why it's not working, looking at previous example

This is the header

```
#ifndef ACCESSPANEL_H
#define ACCESSPANEL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "theislandmain.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QtMultimedia/QSound>

namespace Ui {
    class accessPanel;
}

class accessPanel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit accessPanel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~accessPanel();


private slots:

    QString getCode();

    void on_one_clicked();

    void on_two_clicked();

    void on_three_clicked();

    void on_four_clicked();

    void on_five_clicked();

    void on_six_clicked();

    void on_seven_clicked();

    void on_eight_clicked();

    void on_nine_clicked();

    void on_cancel_clicked();

    void on_zero_clicked();

    void on_confirm_clicked();

private:
    Ui::accessPanel *ui;
    QString input;
    QSound *keypad;
};

#endif // ACCESSPANEL_H
```

This is the main

```
#include "accesspanel.h"
#include "ui_accesspanel.h"
#include <QtMultimedia/QSound>


accessPanel::accessPanel(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::accessPanel)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    keypad = new QSound("../Island/Sounds/keypad.wav", this);
}

accessPanel::~accessPanel()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString accessPanel::getCode()
{
    return input;
}

void accessPanel::on_one_clicked()
{
    keypad->play();
    input = input + "1";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_two_clicked()
{
    input = input + "2";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_three_clicked()
{
    input = input + "3";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_four_clicked()
{
    input = input + "4";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_five_clicked()
{
    input = input + "5";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_six_clicked()
{
    input = input + "6";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_seven_clicked()
{
    input = input + "7";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_eight_clicked()
{
    input = input + "8";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_nine_clicked()
{
    input = input + "9";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_cancel_clicked()
{
    this->close();
    input = "";
    ui->codeDisplay->clear();
}

void accessPanel::on_zero_clicked()
{
    input = input + "0";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

void accessPanel::on_confirm_clicked()
{
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
    TheIslandMain::setInput(input);
    this->close();
}
```

I'm getting the following errors.

> accesspanel.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: void _*thiscall QSound::play(void)"
>   (*_imp_?play@QSound@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "private: void
>   __thiscall accessPanel::on_one_clicked(void)" (?on_one_clicked@accessPanel@@AAEXXZ)
>
> accesspanel.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QSound::QSound(class QString
>   const &,class QObject *)"
>   (_*imp*??0QSound@@QAE@ABVQString@@PAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: __thiscall accessPanel::accessPanel(class QWidget
>   *)" (??0accessPanel@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
>
> accesspanel.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall
>   QSound::metaObject(void)const "
>   (?metaObject@QSound@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

And 3 others similar to it.

I've tried the following

`QSound::play("filename");` - same issues

I messed around with a static reference but got something like

Comment: possible duplicate of [Q\_OBJECT linker error!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264259/q-object-linker-error)

Comment: Tried most of the stuff in that link prior to post (QMake, clean, restart QT, restart PC etc), but I'll go through it again.

Comment: I've deleted the build folder, recompiled, run qmake, rebuilt and most combinations. Error persists.

Comment: Can you post an example contained in one file? You should be able to narrow it down to just a QSound example.

Comment: Sure.

If I remove all QSound references in the header/source and replace the method with the below, I still get errors.

void accessPanel::on_one_clicked()
{
   // keypad->play();
    QSound::play("../Island/Sounds/keypad.wav");
    input = input + "1";
    ui->codeDisplay->setText(input);
}

Comment: Ugh, that looks messy. Is there no way to format code in a reply?

Comment: Error added here.

accesspanel.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl QSound::play(class QString const &)" (__imp_?play@QSound@@SAXABVQString@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall accessPanel::on_one_clicked(void)" (?on_one_clicked@accessPanel@@AAEXXZ) // Second Error // release\Island.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was my .pro file. I needed to add QT += multimedia to my project .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Instead of creating a pointer I create an empty variable in the header:

```
private:
      QSound m_startsound;
```

I assign the value with explicitly mentioning it parent object (thanks for reminding me of that):

```
BloxProcessor::BloxProcessor() : 
     m_showPopup(true),
     ....
     m_startsound("mysounds/hallo.wav",this)
{
....
}
```

You could also do this in the cpp file. In my oppinion less structured solution:

## include

...
QSound m_startsound("mysounds/hallo.wav",this);

However, these solutions could solve loading time in playing a static sound several times. It does not make the sounds changeable on a certain trigger. This requires your pointer structure:
in header
    QPointer p_startsound;

on init or in the constructor set the default value:

```
p_startsound = new QSound("mysounds/he.wav",this);
```

on change trigger be sure to remove the old object to prevent memory leaks

```
BloxProcessor::triggerToChangeSoundActivated()
{
    p_startsound->deleteLater();
    p_startsound = new QSound("mysounds/hallo.wav",this);
}
```

If computing time is of no essence the simple play function can be used

```
QSound::play("mysounds/hallo.wav");
```

BTW
Somehow I don't need to include the multimedia package explicitly for any of these. Perhaps because I use a diferent version of QT or because it is inherited somewhere else in the platform.

EDIT Use a protected QPointer instead otherwise it will crash...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QT5
Please Add Qt5Multimedia.lib in the Additional dependencies at
Project -> Properties->Configuration Propeties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies