# Connect Qt signal and slot in a derived QObject constructor

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am writing a simple `EchoServer` class, inheriting from `QTcpServer`. And when I connect signal and slot in the constructor, it does not go well.

```
class EchoServer : public QTcpServer {
  //Q_OBJECT
public:
  EchoServer(int listenling_port) {
    this->listen(QHostAddress(), listenling_port);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(HandleIncomingConnection()));
  }
public slots:
  void HandleIncomingConnection() {
    auto echo_handler = EchoServerHandler(this->nextPendingConnection());
    echo_handler.Echo();
  }
private:
};
```

The application does listen to the port, and can be telneted. But the console displays

"**QObject::connect: No such slot QTcpServer::HandleIncomingConnection()**",

which seems it is recognizing `this` as a base class `QTcpServer` pointer.

Also if I leave `Q_OBJECT` in the code, it would not compile, saying

"**error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall EchoServer::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@EchoServer@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)**",

are they related?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Q\_OBJECT linker error!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264259/q-object-linker-error)

Comment: @sashoalm Although the link helps. The answers in that link do NOT solve the problem, thus NOT a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to leave `Q_OBJECT` in your code, and you need a destructor to go with your class.

You might need to run "Clean Project" on your code to fix that linker error.

Also check out [Q_OBJECT linker error!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264259/q-object-linker-error)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The link [Q_OBJECT linker error!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264259/q-object-linker-error) in phyatt's answer helps me find the problem. So I'll answer this myself.

The code in the question was put entirely into one `main.cpp` file, which prevents the meta processing of Qt. Put the class definition into a separate `hpp` header and re-compiles, the problem is gone. I am using Visual Studio 2012 + Qt 5.0.